# How to Make a Basic FPS Counter?

Tags: c++, opengl, frame-rate

I'm trying to display my frames-per-second in my cube-rendering program. I would like to see its performance. So, how can I do it? I have done research on this already, but the examples I've seen use either multiple classes and still don't work, or they use libraries that I don't have. Is there a way to get the FPS by using pre-installed libs like ctime? I am using OpenGL with C++.

Here is my (empty) function:

```
void GetFPS()
{

}
```

and then I display my FPS in my render function with:

```
std::cout << xRot << " " << yRot << " " << zRot << " " << FPS << "\n"; //xRot, yRot, and zRot are my cube's rotation.
```

My program is set to 60FPS, but I would like to see the actual FPS, not what it's set to.

Comment: What OS are you running? Different OS' s may require different code.

Comment: I am using Windows, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: May I suggest having a look at time class for my engine: https://github.com/BlackRainInteractive/Splash/tree/master/Splash!/Source/splSystem/Time

Comment: It does use a few functions / classes, but it should help you figure out how to implement your own. Edit: I would post a stripped down version as an answer, but doing that on a tablet is a bit time consuming.

Comment: the problem with the other answer is division by 0, apart that is correct (of course since you will have a time of 0 90% of frame that-s a bit problematic, see my answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate FPS in OpenGL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627803/how-to-calculate-fps-in-opengl)

Comment: The possible duplicate shows one possible way to get a crude approximation to the value.  The answers here are more complete, so I'm not going to vote to close.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to sample 2 different time intervals using `clock()`
however notes that there are several problems:

- resolution of clock is several milliseconds (you may workaround using std::chrono etc, however even chrono may have not so high resolution depending on implementation. On my PC with GCC 4.9.1 I never get better resolution than 16 milliseconds even with std::chrono.
- tipically using `clock()` you will get 0 many times and at some time you will measure a real time (in my case it just make a jump of 15/16 milliseconds)
- unless you are using vertical syncronization (vsync), you will not measure real frametime but just the CPU time spent in your render loop (to activate vsync you have to SetSwapInterval(1) wich your OS function or for example using a library like SDL that provide portable cross platform implementaiton)
- To measure real rendering time you may use a GL'S time query (you may have only 1 timer bound at any time so if you are measuring framerate you cann't measure how long takes render something specific).
- Do not measure FPS (well unless you want just to show it to users), instead measure frame time in milliseconds, that gives much more intuitive approximation of performance. (you know going from 100 to 80 FPS is 2,5 ms difference, going from 40 to 20 FPS is 25 ms difference!)

Do that:

```
double clockToMilliseconds(clock_t ticks){
    // units/(units/time) => time (seconds) * 1000 = milliseconds
    return (ticks/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000.0;
}
//...

clock_t deltaTime = 0;
unsigned int frames = 0;
double  frameRate = 30;
double  averageFrameTimeMilliseconds = 33.333;

while(rendering){

    clock_t beginFrame = clock();
    render();
    clock_t endFrame = clock();

    deltaTime += endFrame - beginFrame;
    frames ++;

    //if you really want FPS
    if( clockToMilliseconds(deltaTime)>1000.0){ //every second
        frameRate = (double)frames*0.5 +  frameRate*0.5; //more stable
        frames = 0;
        deltaTime -= CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        averageFrameTimeMilliseconds  = 1000.0/(frameRate==0?0.001:frameRate);

        if(vsync)
            std::cout<<"FrameTime was:"<<averageFrameTimeMilliseconds<<std::endl;
        else
           std::cout<<"CPU time was:"<<averageFrameTimeMilliseconds<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The above code works also when you do something that takes several seconds. I do a computation that is updated every second, you could as well update it more often. (note I use exactly that code in most of my projects that need FPS)

Comment: good, if you are confused I could refactor the code to make it more readable.

Comment: @Synthetic: Since you're on windows, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter) and [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx). The performance counter should provide you with very high precision (< 1us).

Comment: why need 1000000 times extra precision when the FPS has at most 2 decimal digits?

Comment: This measures the time spent in your render thread. Your system might still be clogged due to driver or GPU load coming from render thread. This method comes up in many answers but not sure if this is a good FPS measurement.

Answer (score 9):

Simply save the time "ticks" before and after you render your scene, then do a simple calculation.

Here's an example that uses `<ctime>`'s `clock()` function. (note that `clock()` works differently on different platform)

```
clock_t current_ticks, delta_ticks;
clock_t fps = 0;
while(true)// your main loop. could also be the idle() function in glut or whatever
{
    current_ticks = clock();

    render();

    delta_ticks = clock() - current_ticks; //the time, in ms, that took to render the scene
    if(delta_ticks > 0)
        fps = CLOCKS_PER_SEC / delta_ticks;
    cout << fps << endl;
}
```

Comment: So I just now tried that, but it appears that delta_ticks never goes above 0? I made sure that my theory is correct by putting an exit(0) inside the if statement, and it never quit.(I ran it for about a minute.)

Comment: @Synthetic Maybe `clock()` is not precise enough? You should try `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

Comment: With APIs like OpenGL, where rendering happens asynchronously on the GPU, this will not measure the actual rendering time.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I replaced the two clock() functions with your idea of std::chrono::... but a compile error comes up saying: Error: expected primary-expression before  ';' token   Error: expected primary-expression before '-' token.  My code function looks like this now: `current_ticks = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

    delta_ticks = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock - current_ticks;
    if(delta_ticks > 0)
    {
        FPS = CLOCKS_PER_SEC / delta_ticks;
        exit(0);
    }
    std::cout << FPS;`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well, that will negatively affect the performance, so you would get a Heisenberg effect. Also, there are GPU vendors who don't finish rendering when you call `glFinish()`.

Comment: Oh crap, sorry that it's super hard to read the code!(Just look for the semicolons to determine a new line)

Comment: After running my program for even longer, the delta_ticks DOES go above 0, in fact, it was locking at 1000? This result was consistence after about 3 minutes of run time.

Comment: I tried the code I wrote. It works as expected. Try replacing `render()` with a `Sleep()` function in order to investigate how it works.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I thought about it. In fact, that advice of mine was a mistake. OP don't need `glFinish()` here, because actual rendering time is not important in this case. I'll delete that comment.

Comment: happy division by 0!  glFinish will just send all commands to GPU. how long the GPU takes to process them is unknown, unless you use specific funcionality like timer querys! See my answer

Comment: @DarioOO Did you miss the if statement?

Comment: YES :D apparently totally missed it

Answer (score 5):

just call this in any loop to measure the number of calls a second.

```
#include <chrono>

void printFPS() {
    static std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> oldTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    static int fps; fps++;

    if (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - oldTime) >= std::chrono::seconds{ 1 }) {
        oldTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "FPS: " << fps <<  std::endl;
        fps = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure FPS only for the sake of printing it, you may use `std::chrono` as it measures wall clock. Using `std::clock()` results in a more accurate value than `std::chrono` since it measures processing time, but maybe you don't want to print FPS with such a high precision.

The solution below uses `std::chrono` to calculate a program's uptime and increments a frame counter after each frame update. Dividing the frame counter by the program's uptime gives you the FPS.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono;

steady_clock::time_point first_tp;
unsigned long frame_count = 0;

duration<double> uptime()
{
    if (first_tp == steady_clock::time_point{})
        return duration<double>{ 0 };

    return steady_clock::now() - first_tp;
}

double fps()
{
    const double uptime_sec = uptime().count();

    if (uptime_sec == 0)
        return 0;

    return frame_count / uptime_sec;
}

void time_consuming_function()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds{ 100 });
}

void run_forever()
{
    std::cout << "fps at first: " << fps() << '\n';

    first_tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "fps: " << fps() << '\n';
        
        time_consuming_function();

        frame_count++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    run_forever();
}
```

Running it on my machine produces:

```
$ ./measure_fps
fps at first: 0
fps: 0
fps: 9.99108
fps: 9.99025
fps: 9.98997
fps: 9.98984
```

Whereas adapting it to `std::clock()` gives

```
$ ./measure_fps
fps at first: 0
fps: 0
fps: 37037
fps: 25316.5
fps: 23622
fps: 22346.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast and complete

```
#include <time.h>   // clock
#include <stdio.h>  // snprintf

unsigned int iMemClock, iCurClock, iLoops;
char aFPS[12];

/* main loop */
{
    if (iMemClock > (iCurClock = clock()))
        iLoops++;
    else
    {
        snprintf(aFPS, sizeof(aFPS),"FPS: %d",iLoops);
        iMemClock = iCurClock + CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        iLoops = 0;
    }

    /*
    someRoutines(); 
    */
}
/* main loop */
```

Comment: `clock()` is not the best function for this, since it doesn't count sleep time, and possibly more.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of these to work. Here is my solution using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654258/get-millisecond-part-of-time) for getting ms.

```
// Gets the time in milliseconds
#include <chrono>
typedef std::chrono::system_clock Clock;

auto ms() {
    auto now = Clock::now();
    auto seconds = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now);
    auto fraction = now - seconds;

    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(fraction);
    return milliseconds.count();
}

// Main loop
auto prevTime = ms();
while (running) {
  frames++;

  processRender();

  if (deltaTime >= 1000) {
    // Do something here every second
    second();
    deltaTime = 0;
    frames = 0;
  }

  auto currTime = ms();
  diff = currTime - prevTime;
  if (diff > 0) {
    deltaTime += diff;
  }
  prevTime = currTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted was a framerate that is sufficiently accurate, but also doesn't jump around too much, so what i came up with was calculating the frames during an interval (like 100ms) and then smoothing that over a window (like the last 10 intervals, so 1 second).

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

template <uint16_t Window>
class RollingAverage
{
private:
    uint16_t m_index = 0;
    uint16_t m_count = 0;
    uint32_t m_previous_inputs[Window];
    uint64_t m_sum = 0;

public:
    uint32_t operator()(uint32_t input, double factor = 1.0)
    {
        m_sum -= m_previous_inputs[m_index];
        m_sum += input;
        m_previous_inputs[m_index] = input;
        if (++m_index == Window) m_index = 0;

        return static_cast<uint32_t>(
            std::lround((factor * m_sum) / (m_count < Window ? ++m_count : Window)));
    }
};

template <uint16_t Window = 10, uint32_t IntervalMS = 100>
class FrameCounter
{
private:

    RollingAverage<Window> m_rolling_average;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> m_previous_time;
    uint32_t m_previous_frame_count = 0;
    uint32_t m_frame_count = 0;
    uint32_t m_fps = 0;

public:
    void next_frame()
    {
        m_frame_count++;
        auto current_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(current_time - m_previous_time);
        if (duration.count() >= IntervalMS)
        {
            m_fps = m_rolling_average(m_frame_count - m_previous_frame_count, 1000.0 / IntervalMS);
            m_previous_frame_count = m_frame_count;
            m_previous_time = current_time;
        }
    }

    uint32_t fps() const { return m_fps; }
};
```

With the default settings (i.e. `FrameCounter<>`) it calculates the number of frames over the last 100ms and then smooths that over a 1 second window. This seems to work pretty well. You can see what it looks like without smoothing by setting the window to `1` (i.e. `FrameCounter<1>`) and it's not quite as easy on the eye.

[image]