# Is there a way to get the frame rate output by the GPU in C++?

Tags: c++, frame-rate

E.g. If I was playing a game, is there any API in C++ I could use to read the FPS currently output by the GPU?

Comment: On Windows this can be done with Event Tracing for Windows.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530798/how-to-make-a-basic-fps-counter

Comment: The gpu doesn't have a frame rate. Are you asking about getting the frame rate of a game externally?

Comment: @George yep that's it

Comment: @Janl1 but that's for someone who has written a game themselves and can control when the next frame is rendered. I'd like to get the fps of a game in general